# Display UIActivityIndicator in viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I am working on an application that fetches data from a webserver through JSON into a `UITableViewController`.

It take time to load data so I want to display a spinner during the loading time in `viewDidLoad`.

This is my first application so I will need a bit more briefing on how to do it.

### `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *categoryId = catId;
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"categoryId=%@",categoryId];
    NSString *cat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&cityId=%@",cityId];
    NSString *hostStr = @"http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/bycategory.json.php?";
    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:cat];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
    NSError *error;
    productsRaw = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    products = [productsRaw objectForKey:@"products"];
    productKeys = [products allKeys];
}
```

Comment: just create an instance of UIActivityIndicator and add it as a subview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create the activity indicator
    UIActivityIndicator *indicator = [UIActivityIndicator alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGrey];

    // add it
    [self.view addSubview:indicator];

    // animate it
    [indicator startAnimating];

    // your code
    NSString *categoryId = catId;
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"categoryId=%@",categoryId];
    NSString *cat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&cityId=%@",cityId];
    NSString *hostStr = @"http://localhost:8888/iphone-so/bycategory.json.php?";
    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
    hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:cat];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
    NSError *error;
    productsRaw = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    products = [productsRaw objectForKey:@"products"];
    productKeys = [products allKeys];

    // stop animating the indicator
    [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) just add MBProgressHUD.h and MBProgressHUD.m files to your project (you may need to convert to ARC if you have enabled ARC)

```
    // Add right after your [super viewDidLoad]; ] your start connection method or in viewdidload whatever....
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.labelText = @"Loading...";

     // rest of the code goes here
}


// Add at start of requestFinished AND requestFailed
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have added `viewDidLoad` method to the question I am worrying how will i use the above code.

Comment: you need to either implement your `UIActivityIndicator` method or download `MBProgressHUD` and use it. you just added your viewdidload code  so what?